# API for Tracking changes / viewing revisions for Microsoft Word

Tags: node.js, ms-word, office365, add-in

In Microsoft Word, there is an option to track changes/view revisions pertaining to a specific document. I would like to know if there is any API to access those changes via an Office Add-In.

Also, via this  [link](http://www.officejs.org/forum/Track-changes-in-word-document-content-control-IYIvJ5zGEo), the consensus is that there is no such API available. But since, this is an old post, we would like to know if the situation has changed.

Furthermore, according to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821680.aspx), there is the presence of Reviewer object for VBA shown. However, is it valid for Office Add-In? If yes, Is it supported in other programming languages like Node.js. If it does, are there any code samples available?

Comment: did you found any workaround for this problem??

Answer (score 3):

The functionality you are asking about is still not supported in the JavaScript API for Word. Please make sure to add this request (or vote for an existing one) [in our user voice channel](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/163566-add-in-word). thanks.